# Automating source IP of OpenSearch using Boto3/Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch

Every time our IPs change, I have to keep updating this policy to access Kibana. I thought I could automate this, but is there any way I can delete an existing policy and create a new one on Lambda? I'm unable to find anything on Boto3 regarding this.

```
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-south-1:xxxxxxxxxxx/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "xxxxxxxx",
            "xxxxxxx",
            "xxxxxxxxx",
            "xxxxxxxxx"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ensure that you IP does not change? Is the IP of some EC2 instance?

Comment: hey, the IPs belong to us employees. We're restricting access to Kibana. So these IPs belong to the employees that can access Kibana.  I just wanted to know if there's a way to delete the existing IP-based policy and create a new one with the Updated IPs of the employees as the IPs keep changing. Can't find anything on boto3.

Answer (score 0):

In boto3 you can use [update_elasticsearch_domain_config](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/es.html#ElasticsearchService.Client.update_elasticsearch_domain_config) which has the option `AccessPolicies`. So basically you have to **overwrite** the entire policy. You can't just modify directly the IP addresses.